# java expression match

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a code to replace some expression as follows

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    str=str.replaceAll("http\\S+", "URL ");  //used answer given
    System.out.println(str);
```

I am giving input

`iCloud hits 20M users http://www.google.com/HTpUTBFK via @cnet`

and want to output

`ENGLISH URL ENGLISH @cnet`

but I am getting

`iCloud hits 20M users URL @cnet`.

After that I want to modify it to

```
ENGLISH URL @cnet
```

The modification changes all the parts of sentence not following a special character(like #,%,@ etc.) to ENGLISH.

Comment: why do you capture a single dot and slash and also put it in a useless group?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to replace the web address, the regex can be much simpler:

```
http\\S+
```

And that's all!

It scans for `http` and then all the non spaces it can find. It stops at the first space.

To be on the safe side and avoid the case of some word starting with http you could make the regex a bit longer and safer:

```
'http://\\S+'
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius.

Comment: Great suggestion! You could also start it with "https?://" to match links starting with both http and https.

Comment: If I want to change "Big mo: In one week http://www.google.co.in/HTp via @cnet"  to "ENGLISH URL ENGLISH @cnet" . Like after changing url to URL ,I want to change other parts of sentence not followed by a special character(@,& etc.) to ENGLISH.            How to do that?

Comment: @Tetragrammaton you shouldn't expand the scope of your question in a comment to an answer. Please either edit your question to better suit your needs or ask a new question, if editing it would change too much.

Comment: @dorukayhan Am not, but it's a nice comment, and it also made me laugh. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion

Comment: Btw, `http://\\S+` is syntactically incorrect. Since they specify where does a regex start and end, forward slashes should be escaped like this: `http:\/\/\\S+`

Answer (score 0):

```
 str=str.replaceAll("http://"+"[\\w|\\.|/]*"+"\\s", "URL ");
```

Using this should work for you, it starts to match from http:// and matches any normal character, dots and slashes until it encounters a space. Then replaces it with "URL ".

You could also start it with `"https?://"` to match links starting with both http and https.

Comment: actually your code is working but partially . Can I edit the question to show  how??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str=str.replaceAll("http://" + ".*([.]).*([/])\\w*" + "\\s", "URL ");
```

you are using `.*` is your code. Its match all string with next space. I do not know why it not working. But if you use `\\w` in place of `.*` then your code will work.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

you may try this,

```
str=str.replaceAll("((www\\.[^\\s]+)|(https?://[^\\s]+))", "URL");
```